# Macro in Personal.xlsb - Active workbook reference

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel macro for some datefield changes. This macro should run for all excel documents/workbooks for a specific user. With my current macro below in the "for each" function it references to my Personal.xlsb and the macro will run on Personal.xlsb workbook. The changes with the datefields should appear in the opened File and not in the Personal.xlsb.
Is there a way to fix this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim arrTargetFields As Variant
Dim strTimeReplacement As String
Dim strDateReplacement As String
Dim arrReplacements As Variant
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

arrTargetFields = Array("&D", "&T")
strTimeReplacement = "TimeSampleText"
strDateReplacement = "DateSampleText" 
arrReplacements = Array(strDateReplacement, strTimeReplacement)

For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    For i = 0 To 1
        With sht.PageSetup
            .LeftHeader = Replace(.LeftHeader, arrTargetFields(i), arrReplacements(i))
            .CenterHeader = Replace(.CenterHeader, arrTargetFields(i), arrReplacements(i))
            .RightHeader = Replace(.RightHeader, arrTargetFields(i), arrReplacements(i))
            'Replace Headers
            .LeftFooter = Replace(.LeftFooter, arrTargetFields(i), arrReplacements(i))
            .CenterFooter = Replace(.CenterFooter, arrTargetFields(i), arrReplacements(i))
            .RightFooter = Replace(.RightFooter, arrTargetFields(i), arrReplacements(i))
            'Replace Footers
        End With
    Next i
Next sht

Set sht = Nothing

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Change `ThisWorkbook` to `ActiveWorkbook`?

Comment: Also, if you're looping over worksheets, use the correct collection: `For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`. Otherwise, if the workbook contains a chart, an error will occur.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The changes remain to be in the personal.xlsb with these changes. Maybe the issue is where I store the macro? The macro is stored in the personal.xlsb. I think I need this so all excel documents get the changes by opening. @VBasic2008

Comment: It works when I manually run the macro with "ActiveWorkbook.Sheets". But it does nothing when I want to do it with the Workbook_Open. Any advice?